# Using Image I/O to create thumbnail from programatically created UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am trying to use image I/O to create thumbnails from a UIImage that I have created programatically. the problem is that the image that is returned is nil.

```
    -( UIImage *)       thumbnailFromImage: ( UIImage *)image
    {

        CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider( image.CGImage );
        CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithDataProvider( dataProvider, NULL );

        NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform,
                                 (id)kCFBooleanTrue, (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways,
                                 (id)[NSNumber numberWithFloat:160.f], (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize,
                                 nil];

        CGImageRef thumbnail = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex( src, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(options) );

        UIImage* smallImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:thumbnail scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        return smallImage;   
    }
```

Has anybody have any suggestions.
thanks

Reza

Comment: Is `CGImageGetDataProvider` returning NULL?

Comment: No, CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex is returning nil

Comment: I have heard from Apple that this can not be done. Image I/O needs to be used for reading files from the disk